# Reopening class which includes Mongoid::Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a simple class:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
end
```

And I would like to reopen it to add a Mongoid callback:

```
class User
  before_create :do_this
  def do_this
    # do it...
  end
end
```

Unfortunately I got the error: `undefined method 'before_create' for User:Class`

Any idea how to do this ? Should I use a mixin pattern instead of re-opening ?

**UPDATE**: I can't change the original class definition, since it's in a shared library. And the load order is tricky, because it's in Rails. The original class is in a file loaded in `autoload_path`. Where should I reopen it ? And I would rather use a module rather than reopening, but I'm not sure it's possible to include my module "from the outside" !

**UPDATE 2**: You are right, it's just a load order problem. So now my question becomes: **Since Rails' autoload is lazy, how can I force Rails to load my reopening file after it loads the original class file ? :)**

Comment: Are you sure that the first class definition is loaded before the class reopening? Your example should work. Try to put them into a single file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above worked for me in the console.  I suspect the second class declaration is being loaded first.  You might try printing out a message immediately inside each class declaration e.g.

```
class User
  puts "First"
  ...
end

...

class User
  puts "Second"
  ...
end
```

and verifying that they load in the correct order.

Also, if you do have access to the first class declaration, you might use a mixin if possible, as it keeps everything for the User class in a single location.

**UPDATE**: Can you first load/require the shared User class to ensure it is loaded?  That is:

```
require 'app/models/user'

class User
  before_create :do_something
  def do_something
    ...
  end
end
```